# Flutter Localization on Web without reload page

Tags: flutter, localization

I am developing a project which supports Android, iOS, and Web.
I am using https://pub.dev/packages/easy_localization
When I switch the language, it is working good on Android and iOS app. However, on web it doesn't change language immediately unless I refresh the page.

Is there any solution to change the language on the website without reloading the page?

Answer (score 1):

**Here the latest and simpler version to generate [easy_localization 3.0.3](https://pub.dev/packages/easy_localization)**

> Here the terminal commands for implementing lang classess and keys
>
> Firstly run this commmand

```
dart run easy_localization:generate -h
```

> This command used to generate lang file mention your path also

```
dart run  easy_localization:generate --source-dir ./assets/translations -O lib/translations
```

> This command used for generate keys

```
dart run easy_localization:generate --source-dir ./assets/translations -O lib/translations -o locale_keys.g.dart -f keys
```

> Main file will be

```
 Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await EasyLocalization.ensureInitialized();
  // Initialize Shared preferance
  await SharedPref().init();
  //initialise dependancy injection//
  await getInit();
//initialise Hive local storage//
  await HiveConfig.initConfig();

  runApp(
    EasyLocalization(
      supportedLocales: const [Locale('en'), Locale('ar')],
      path: 'assets/translations',
      fallbackLocale: const Locale('en'),
      assetLoader: const CodegenLoader(),
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

///Route widget
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  ///Constructor
  MyApp({super.key});
  final _appRoutes = AppRouter();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => servicelocator<AuthenticationBloc>(),
      child: MaterialApp.router(
        localizationsDelegates: context.localizationDelegates,
        supportedLocales: context.supportedLocales,
        locale: context.locale,
        routerConfig: _appRoutes.config(),
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        scaffoldMessengerKey: snackbarKey,
        theme: lightTheme,
        // darkTheme: darkTheme,
        // themeMode: ThemeMode.system,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use easy_localization generate feature you don't have this issue anymore since your lang files are generated in your Dart code

Generates the lang file :

```
flutter pub run easy_localization:generate --source-dir ./assets/languages -O lib/languages
```

Generates the key file :

```
flutter pub run easy_localization:generate --source-dir ./assets/languages -O lib/languages -o locale_keys.g.dart -f keys
```

Add `assetLoader` to your `EasyLocalization` config

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(EasyLocalization(
      child: MyApp(),
      supportedLocales: [Locale('en', 'US'), Locale('ar', 'DZ')],
      path: 'resources/langs',
      assetLoader: CodegenLoader())); //adding assetLoader
}
```